# How to automatically restart a workflow when a task is locked?

Tags: workflow, task-list

I get the following error for some workflows. Restarting them always solves the problem, but doing this manually for each instance is not practical in our setup.

> This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited.

From what I have found out, there is a WorkflowVersion flag with the tasklist item associated with the workflow which is set to a value != 1 whenever there is an error. Once I have detected this error how do I restart the workflow? Or are there any other ways to tackle this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please tag by feature or topic and not by version (or product). This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue, you need to change the taskId from fixed GUID to dynamic GUID.
More Information is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurasa/archive/2010/05/31/task-is-currently-locked-by-a-running-workflow-and-cannot-be-edited.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Pause or Wait action in a designer workflow which will wait for a field change